# How do I apply for a UK standard visit visa for a 2-year-old child?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, minors

My husband holds a UK business visa and asked me to apply for a visit visa.

I have filled in my application and entered my uncle's address under the question of where I plan to stay. I am trying to give the same address for my child, as well, but it keeps asking me the relationship between my uncle and my child. As it isn't an option for direct family, I cannot proceed further.

I read previous answers here that mention a GWF number, but I don't understand where to mention it in the online application.

Also, what do I put in for the question about how much I plan to spend in the UK?

Comment: Your uncle is your child's great uncle.